# Change characters to uppercase on Big Cartel header/footer navigation

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I am trying to change all header and footer navigation in my big cartel store to fully uppercase.
Ones I have added myself are fine however the existing "Collections", "Home" & "Contact" options need to be changed.
How would I do this?
The theme is "Neat" if this makes a difference.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the CSS and inserting `text-transform` property to the right selectors.
basically if you add `text-transform: uppercase;` to the right selector it would change the text to uppercase.

---

you can read more about text-transform in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform